# Couldn't sign in to google using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make an auto gift card redeemer, and I made this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as ec
import time

email = input("Email >> ")
password = input("Pass >> ")
gc_number = input("Number of giftcard >> ")
directory = input("Code file directory >> ")


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

driver.get("https://play.google.com/")
signin = driver.find_element_by_id("gb_70")
signin.click()
usr = driver.find_element_by_name("identifier")
usr.clear()
usr.send_keys(email)
usrsubmit = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext")
usrsubmit.click()
pwd = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
pwd.clear()
pwd.send_keys(password)
pwdsubmit = driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext")
pwdsubmit.click()
redeem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("gm1qLe")
redeem.click()


for i in range(gc_number):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("whsOnd zHQkBf")
    elem.clear()
    code_file = open(directory, "r")
    code = code_file.readlines()
    code_file.close()
    elem.send_keys(code[i])
    elem.submit()
```

but, I got this error message

> Couldn't sign you in
>
> This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
>
> Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported
> browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

pls help me, how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using?

Comment: I use 79.0.3945

Comment: If you use v79 to manually do what your selenium script does, do you get the same warning?

Comment: yes, if I use the tab that my selenium tab opened

Comment: That is not what I'm asking. If you manually open the browser window and manually perform the same steps as your script, do you get the same warning?

Comment: no, I can login successfully